# Resolve a System.Web.Services.WebService instance with Castle (for AOP purposes)

Tags: .net, web-services, castle-windsor, asmx, aop

I wanted to implement logging for an existing web service with an interceptor; in the project we're using a System.Web.Services.WebService class (those associated with asmx.cs files), but all the examples I've found online use the castle's wcf facility.

Is there a way to register and resolve a System.Web.Services.WebService instance with Castle?

Comment: It shouldn't surprise you to find no examples of using a modern product (Castle) with a legacy technology (ASMX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you can proxy an asmx WebService. IIRC the model for asmx web services is similar to ASP.NET WebForms, so [the same limitations apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783287/using-castle-windsor-with-interceptors-and-asp-net/4784450#4784450).

Comment: Thanks, I made the WebService totally dumb, and all its webmethods call a proxy resolved by Castle (with the same interface as the WebService). :)