# Windsor webservice inject properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I have a MVC application and inject my repositories to my controller what works properly.
Additionally I have a Webservice in my solution which uses exactly the same repositories but when my Webservice is called my repository properties are null.

I register my repositories the following way:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HdtRepository))).InSameNamespaceAs<HdtRepository>().WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestyleTransient());
```

my repository properties look like:

```
  public IUserRepository _userRepo { get; set; }
    public IHdtRepository _hdtRepo { get; set; }
    public ITimeRecordRepository _timeRepo { get; set; }
```

Can someone tell me why the repositories are not injected to my webservice?

For now I added the following to the constructor of my webservice:

```
 public MyWebservice()
     {
        _userRepo = MvcApplication.container.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
        _hdtRepo = MvcApplication.container.Resolve<IHdtRepository>();
        _timeRepo = MvcApplication.container.Resolve<ITimeRecordRepository>();
        _locationRepo = MvcApplication.container.Resolve<ILocationRepository>();
        _wayRepo = MvcApplication.container.Resolve<IWayPointRepository>();
        _wayDataRepo = MvcApplication.container.Resolve<IWayDataRepository>();
    }
```

but as far as I know this is actually a antipattern.
I'm new to all that IoC stuff so could someone please tell me where the problem is.

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Why are you using property injection anyway? You should use constructor injection.

Comment: Agree on the ctor injection comment. As well you may want to try registering your components with the windsor container by interface not by typeof. This way you can control the lifestyle of the component. As things sit now your registration code states that everything is singleton, this is the default if not explicitly defined by another lifestlye; trainsient or perwebrequest.

Comment: Sorry for that question but why is property injection that bad? Isn't it acutally the same? Since c# 3.0 I have the possibility to use: Test asdf = new Test(){Prop1=1234, Prop2="asdf"} and there is no need anymore for lots of different constructors.

Comment: and when I use this code to register my repositories my controller properties are also not injected anymore:

container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<,>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(RepositoryBase<,>)).LifeStyle.Transient);

Comment: I implemented it exactly the way id is described in this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle#Repositories  excepting the UoW stuff since this breaks LazyLoading

Comment: Ok,
I changed to constructor injection in my controller and my webservice.
I guess now I have to change the "WebserviceFactory" if there is something like that. Same as I had to do with "ControllerFactory" since there are only parameterless constructors suppoerted.

Answer (score 0):

First lets get your project setup with some Windsor installers. They look like this for the most part.

```
  public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
               container.Register(Component.For<IEncryptionService().ImplementedBy<EncryptionService>());

    }
}
```

in your App_Start folder add a class called ContainerConfig.cs that could look something like this.

```
  public class ContainerConfig
{
    private static IWindsorContainer _container;

    public static IWindsorContainer ConfigureContainer()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        _container.Install(FromAssembly.This()).Install(FromAssembly.Named("Project.Dependency"));
        _container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(_container.Kernel, true));
        _container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(_container.Kernel);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
        return _container;
    }
}
```

Please note that I have a separate project for my Dependency Injection hence the _container.Install(FromAssembly.This()).Install(FromAssembly.Named("Project.Dependency")); line...  You can remove the latter .Install(FromAssembly) part.

In your Global.asax you can do something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ContainerConfig.ConfigureContainer();

    }
```

Now in your controllers you can do this:

```
 public class TempController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEncryptionService _encryptionService;

    public TempController(IEncryptionService encryptionService )
    {
        _encryptionService = encryptionService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Example of calling a method on the encryption service.
        string hash, salt;
        _encryptionService.GethashAndSaltString("I Need Some Loving", out hash, out salt);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you get something working with constructor injection. Solving that issue will be a great help going forward and you won't be using property injection. Once we get all of that sorted out we can look at your webervice issues.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that code but I think I already have that stuff.
I implemented my application based on this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle#Repositories

Comment: Ok, I changed to constructor injection in my controller and my webservice. I guess now I have to change the "WebserviceFactory" if there is something like that. Same as I had to do with "ControllerFactory" since there are only parameterless constructors suppoerted.

Comment: Haha... Definately not! This has nothing to do with my question!!

Comment: Not sure about your comment. I think my answer helped you. You switched to constructor injection rather than use the terrible code you posted. Then you leave a jerky ass response. Nice, very professional. We never got to your webservice because you never responded back.

Comment: Thats ridiculous. You are just one of that guys that don't really read a article and just want to get some points by posting something that has nothing to do with the question asked... I'm going to ask an admin if I should mark your respone as answer... Ok?

Comment: I asked if it was helpful to please mark it as an answer. I don't care much for virtual rep / points. I was honestly trying to help you and you made a rude unprofessional remark. That type of attitude is childish and most likely won't get you much help in the future.

Comment: You can tell this your grandpa! 1.) You answered a question never asked. Only guys who want to get more reputation points work that way since they just post a lot of crap and hope someone marks it as answer. 2.) You asked me to mark it as anwer (because it may be helpful). 3.) Your "answer" pointed me in the wrong direction because you can't use constructor in injection in .asmx webservice (read my answer). 4.) also thanks for voting this down, is my question onclear or do you need further information?
I'm sorry but im pissed of such people!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not possible as far as I've read some other posts.
The problem is that you can't create a custom factory for a Webservice like "WindsorControllerFactory" for the controller.
I'm going to switch to WCF Service.

[Resolve a System.Web.Services.WebService instance with Castle (for AOP purposes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852175/resolve-a-system-web-services-webservice-instance-with-castle-for-aop-purposes)